# Cost Function in keras

Tags: autoencoder

How do I implement a network cost function of type autoencoder in keras based on the database labels. The examples of this base have labels 0 and 1. I did the form presented below, I do not know if it is correct.

```
def loss_function (x):
    def function(y_true, y_pred):
        for i in range (batch_size):
            if x[i]==0:
            print('valorA',x[i])
            L1=K.mean(K.square(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]))
            else:
            print('valorB',x[i])
            L2=K.mean(K.square(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]))      
    return L1+L2

return function
```

> compilação do autoencoder

```
autoencoder.compile(loss=loss_function(labeltr),optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info on efforts you made and share some code.

Comment: def loss_function (x):
   def function(y_true, y_pred):
       for i in range (batch_size):
            if x[i]==0:
             print('valorA',x[i])
             L1=K.mean(K.square(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]))
            else:
             print('valorB',x[i])
             L2=K.mean(K.square(y_pred[i] - y_true[i]))      
       return L1+L2

Comment: Add code to original question and format that properly. It will help others to help you.